# create var in a array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello Ihave some question.
first I have to say that my english isnt so good. Sorry for it.

my problem is:

In my PHP script are some Vars like

```
var $_email = 'no';
var $_fname = 'no';
var $_lname = 'no';
```

etc.

The vars will init if the user visit my page. but now I want to init the vars autom. from a sql column array... like:

```
$query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $column[] = $row["Field"];
}

foreach($column as $value)
{
var $value = 'no';
}
```

if somebody understand what i mean please help me..

Comment: the query i made is `  $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $column[] = $row["Field"];
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use something called [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (sounds strange, I know).

Here's an example:

```
$column = array('_email', '_fname', '_lname');

foreach($column as $value)
{
    $$value = 'no';
}

echo $_email . '<br>';
echo $_fname . '<br>';
echo $_lname . '<br>';
```

**BUT bare in mind that I don't recommend this. Using [associative arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is a much better approach (ashes999's response is the right choice to go).**

Here's the same example with an associative array:

```
$column = array('_email', '_fname', '_lname');

foreach($column as $value)
{
    $arrValues[$value] = 'no';
}

echo $arrValues['_email'] . '<br>';
echo $arrValues['_fname'] . '<br>';
echo $arrValues['_lname'] . '<br>';
```

One variable ($arrValues) - everything in one place.

**[Arrays can be very powerful](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)** if you learn how to use them. And PHP has the luxury of having associative arrays.

Also, when declaring variables in PHP, there's no need for the keyword `var`. That's in other languages, like JavaScript for example.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Hmm, downflagged. Although, I stated that variable variables aren't the way to go. It's just an approach, an interesting feature of PHP that other languages don't have.

Comment: And I meant it about having the luxury of associative arrays. Trying to do tasks that involve arrays, in Delphi 7 for example (which doesn't know associative arrays) can be very painful. 3 lines in PHP code can become 20 in Delphi equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with a key/value approach. When you query the database, store the values in an associative array.

eg. if you ran:

`SELECT email, fName, lName FROM ...`

then you would save them as:

```
someArray['email'] = $result['email'];
someArray['fName'] = $result['fName'];
someArray['lName'] = $result['lName'];
```

Or something similar.

Comment: I get the columns like... $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM user";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $column[] = $row["Field"]; and every column be a var how containing "no".
  }